# Is this stack suitable for abstract optimisation algorithm questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm a little unclear about the intent of this stack - I've only just come across it.

Is it suitable for "I have this situation which I'd like to optimise, and I don't know whether there's an algorithm to calculating/constructing the optimal solution?" type questions.

i.e. if TSP wasn't a known problem would "how do I optimise <description of TSP>" be on-topic here?

Comment: Sample of the sort of question i have in mind: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7730/maximal-matching-in-a-constrained-unweighted-bipartite-graph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we are open to "what flavor problem is this" and "what algorithms are applicable here" questions.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @prubin's direct answer, [this Page](https://or.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) gives a detailed description of what's on-topic.
(didn't know these pages existed! ‍♂️)